# AnimatedSwitcher not animating from method?

Tags: flutter, animation

Any ideea why AnimatedSwitcher not animating when done inside a method like the following?

I mean, the switch happens, it's not transitioned with animation.

```
Widget _buildSwitchableWidget({
    @required bool state,
    @required Widget widget1,
    @required Widget widget2,
  }) {
    final widget = !state ? widget1 : widget2;
    return AnimatedSwitcher(
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 350),
      transitionBuilder: (Widget child, Animation<double> animation) {
        return FadeTransition(
          child: child,
          opacity: animation,
        );
      },
      child: widget,
    );
  }
```

I am having a hard time understanding why is his happening, since calling AnimatedSwitcher normally works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try calling SetState when state is change and if your widget1 and widget2 are same type then give them a key so that flutter can identify them separately.

You can follow [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2W7POjFb88g) for more info.